# How to handle children of droppable element on drop?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have some specific situation this:
[image]
picture shows it very good. So I'm developing following actions:

- Sortable Div has method `.sortable()` on itself. And sortable Items sorts well.
- DroppableDiv has method `.droppable()` on itself. And DragItems has method `.draggable()` on theirself.

**My issue**

What I want to do is to handle sortable item on which was dropped DragItem from Container. 
[image]

In this example I'm drag & drop `DragItem 2` to `Sortable Item 2`. And I need to handle `Sortable Item 2` within `DroppableDiv.droppable({drop : function(event, ui) {}});`.

I've searched `event` and `ui` object but I haven't find solution there.

Also sorry I haven't give anny fiddle but I have problem with create working example in jsfiddle/jsBin.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case I have wrote my own function:

```
function findPosition(position) {
    var container = $("#DroppableDiv");
    var sortableItems = container.find("li");
    var searchedItem = null;

    for (var i = 0; i < sortableItems.length; i++) {
        var item = sortableItems.eq(i);
        var itemPosition = item.position();
        var itemWidth = item.css('width');
        var itemHeight = item.css('length');

        if (position.left < parseFloat(widgetPosition.left) + (parseFloat(widgetWidth) * 0.75) && position.top < parseFloat(widgetPosition.top) + (parseFloat(widgetHeight) * 0.75)) {
            searchedItem = widget;
            break;
        }
    }

    return searchedItem;
}
```

Which was called from:

```
    $("#DroppableDiv").droppable({
        accept: 'li',
        drop: function (event, ui) {
            //here is little trick for check is event comes from drag or sort(only in my case)
            if (ui.draggable.context.childElementCount === 0) {
                var newWidgetPosition = findPosition(ui.position);
            }
        }
    });
```